# Função onChange não funciona quando aplicada a vários campos

Tags: html, ajax

Uso a função *onChange="getPeca(1);"*, onde é acessado um JS que alimenta o campo ao lado com a descrição. Isso funciona, se eu diretamente no campo e digitar o código e dar tab ele faz a pesquisa corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Agora, se eu faço a pesquisa do formulário todo, usando um Ajax, ele só traz o código, não fazendo a pesquisa vinculada ao input:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No HTML uso o *onChange*. Alguém sabe se existe outra função "melhor"?

```
<td><input type = "text" id="codItem1" name = "codItem1" size = 10 maxlength =5 placeholder="Código 1" onChange="getPeca(1);">
```

Script que alimenta todo o formulário:

```
/**
  * Função para criar um objeto XMLHTTPRequest
  */
 function CriaRequest() {
     try{
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (IEAtual){

         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(IEAntigo){

             try{
                 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(falha){
                 request = false;
             }
         }
     }

     if (!request)
         alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
     else
         return request;
}

//Não executa nada até a execução terminar
var requestActive = false;

function getOrdem() {
    if (requestActive) return;
    requestActive = true;
    // Declaração de Variáveis
    /* Caso for necessário passar mais parametros além do nome
     * basta adicionar uma variável aqui e editar no GET
     */
     var ids = ["equipamento", "descrCC", "parada", "data_inicio", "hora_inicio", "hora_parada", "data_fechamento", "tipo_servico_ficha", "tipo_acao",
                "problema", "responsavel", "mecanico_1", "mecanico_2", "mecanico_3", "mecanico_4", "mecanico_5", "mecanico_6", "tipo_servico_1",
                "tipo_servico_2", "tipo_servico_3", "tipo_servico_4", "tipo_servico_5", "tipo_servico_6", "tipo_acao_1", "tipo_acao_2", "tipo_acao_3",
                "tipo_acao_4", "tipo_acao_5", "tipo_acao_6", "tipo_falha_1", "tipo_falha_2", "tipo_falha_3", "tipo_falha_4", "tipo_falha_5", "tipo_falha_6",
                "data_inicio_1", "data_inicio_2", "data_inicio_3", "data_inicio_4", "data_inicio_5", "data_inicio_6", "data_fim_1", "data_fim_2", "data_fim_3",
                "data_fim_4", "data_fim_5", "data_fim_6", "horas_apro_1", "horas_apro_2", "horas_apro_3", "horas_apro_4", "horas_apro_5", "horas_apro_6",
                "min_apro_1", "min_apro_2", "min_apro_3", "min_apro_4", "min_apro_5", "min_apro_6", "acao_1", "acao_2", "acao_3", "acao_4", "acao_5",
                "acao_6", "obs_1",  "obs_2", "obs_3", "obs_4", "obs_5", "obs_6", "codItem1", "codItem2", "codItem3", "codItem4", "codItem5", "codItem6", "codItem7",
                "codItem8", "codItem9", "codItem10", "codItem11", "codItem12", "codItem13", "codItem14", "codItem15", "codItem16", "codItem17", "codItem18", "codItem19",
                "codItem20", "item_qtde_1", "item_qtde_2", "item_qtde_3", "item_qtde_4", "item_qtde_5", "item_qtde_6", "item_qtde_7", "item_qtde_8", "item_qtde_9",
                "item_qtde_10", "item_qtde_11", "item_qtde_12", "item_qtde_13", "item_qtde_14", "item_qtde_15", "item_qtde_16", "item_qtde_17", "item_qtde_18",
                "item_qtde_19", "item_qtde_20", "infos_complementares"];
    var ordem = document.getElementById("ordem").value; //CAMPO QUE VEM DO INDEX.PHP
    var result = document.getElementById("content"); //DIV DE RETORNO DOS DADOS
    var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

    // Exibe a mensagem de progresso
    //result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';
    ids.forEach(function (id) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = 'Aguarde...';
    });

    // Iniciar uma requisição
    // Se for colocar mais variáveis, é aqui. Exemplo: processa.php?txtnome=" + nome + '&admissao=' + admissao
    xmlreq.open("GET", "js/processaOrdem.php?ordem=" + ordem, true);

    // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de estado
    xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi vazio do Oracle
                if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                    document.getElementById("ordem").focus();
                    alert("Não existe a ordem!");
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                        document.getElementById("ordem").value = '';
                    });
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
        requestActive = false;
    };
    xmlreq.send(null);
}
```

Script que alimenta o campo único:

```
/**
  * Função para criar um objeto XMLHTTPRequest
  */
 function CriaRequest() {
     try{
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (IEAtual){

         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(IEAntigo){

             try{
                 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(falha){
                 request = false;
             }
         }
     }

     if (!request)
         alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
     else
         return request;
}

//Não executa nada até a execução terminar
  var requestActive = false;

function getPeca(id_campo) {

   if (requestActive) return;
       requestActive = true;
    // Declaração de Variáveis
    /* Caso for necessário passar mais parametros além do nome
     * basta adicionar uma variável aqui e editar no GET
     */

    var codItem = document.getElementById("codItem" + id_campo).value; //CAMPO QUE VEM DO INDEX.PHP
    var result = document.getElementById("content"); //DIV DE RETORNO DOS DADOS
    var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

    // Exibe a mensagem de progresso
    //result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';
    document.getElementById("desc_item_" + id_campo).value = "Aguarde...";

    // Iniciar uma requisição
    // Se for colocar mais variáveis, é aqui. Exemplo: processa.php?txtnome=" + nome + '&admissao=' + admissao
    xmlreq.open("GET", "js/ProcessaPecaEdicao.php?codItem=" + codItem, true);

    // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de estado
    xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi nulo ou vazio
                if ((xmlreq.responseText == "null") || (xmlreq.responseText == "")) {
                    alert("Item inexistente! Cadastre antes");
                    document.getElementById("codItem" + id_campo).value = '';
                    document.getElementById("desc_item_" + id_campo).value = '';
                    document.getElementById("codItem" + id_campo).focus();
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("item_qtde_" + id_campo).focus();
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                       document.getElementById("desc_item_" + id_campo).value = dados;
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
        requestActive = false;
    };
    xmlreq.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você quis dizer com "Agora, se eu faço a pesquisa do formulário todo, ele só traz o código, não fazendo a pesquisa vinculada ao input". Pode detalhar mais? Além disso, coloque o código de `getPeca()` . O problema pode estar lá.

Comment: Na verdade o *getPeca()* está trazendo todos os 102 campos que preciso, mas nesses inputs, que tem outro ajax, não chama. É como se o input fosse alimentado e ele não reconhecesse por ser oriundo do ajax.

Comment: Então tem dois scripts que você não colocou? Pode colocar os dois?

Comment: Editada a pergunta